# php with progress tag follows another php with different style of progress tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, progress

i have an issue regarding the  tag..

file name: test.php:-

```
 <head>
 <style>

 progress[value] {
 width: 250px;
 height: 20px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }

 </style>
 </head>

 <progress max="100" value="80"></progress>
```

i copy the same code in another php file named test1.php but i change the width and height.. then, what happened is that, when i include both file in one php file to execute it, the output for both progress bar is the same.. the width is the same and so for the height..

anyone knows why?

Comment: _“anyone knows why?”_ – probably because you left the CSS selector as it is, and so using it a second time overwrites the property values set via the first one? Seriously, if this baffles you, then you need to go do some reading-up on the very basics of CSS …

Comment: what do u mean by CSS selector?

Comment: The part of the rule that selects the element(s) that the formatting is applied to – seriously, if you don’t know even that much, then it is absolutely time for you to go learn some CSS basics.